# Where does it curb my gradient gray?

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://www.altradona.ro/) website. As you can see in the [picture](http://i59.tinypic.com/kbwsab.jpg)  there is a gray stripe stripe ... that I want to do a white or delete. Code for my gradient is given below:

```
.top-switch-bg{ 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 20% , #d9d9d9); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, white 20%, #d9d9d9); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, white 20%, #d9d9d9); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 20% , #d9d9d9); /* Standard syntax */
 min-height:29px; position:relative; z-index:10030;
z-index:1;}
```

How can I make this code work as I wish. What's wrong with the code writing?

EDIT:

I solve this problem.
I changed this code

```
header { position:relative; z-index:10020;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
         box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);}
```

with:

```
header { position:relative; z-index:10020;}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't seem to be able to view your site now (was able to see it yesterday) but that bottom gray line shouldn't be because of your gradient. It seems like some border

Comment: just used logo as transplant png. your problem is resolved.

Comment: try moving the right color position to 25%. example: background: linear-gradient(to right, white 25% , #d9d9d9); @cristi